# London gangster movie that came after Lock-Stock

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm trying to find a British gangster movie, which at the time I thought might be another Lock stock and two smoking barrels. I walked out of the cinema early on so I only have a vague description.

Three men in a bar, one shorter and less physically impressive guy is going on about how his hands are lethal weapons (clearly they are not), then he gets stabbed in the stomach. He staggers outside and is leaning against a garage door or some wall, and wincing from the pain, then fade to black.

Then it fades in again, still there, still in pain, fade to black.

Then it fades in *again* still in pain. At that point I left the cinema.

Release year: Probably 1999 or 2000.

Comment: If you want a GOOD movie in the Lock-Stock style: watch [Snatch](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0208092/)

Comment: Or RockNRolla my personal favorite

Comment: Have done and loved it even more than Lock-Stock

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're after [Love, Honor and Obey](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0199727/combined) from 2000 with Jonny Lee Miller, Jude Law and Ray Winstone. It's a crime comedy about London gangsters. The scene is around minute 15: A geeky guy claims his hands are deadly weapons in a pub, Miller stabs him in the stomach in response, the guy is carried out by 2 burly guys and left by the side of the road; Fade out, fade in and he's still in pain; Fade out, fade in and he decides to call an ambulance (but has no reception). Here's the scene:

Comment: Brilliant. Now I can see if I was right to walk out.

Comment: @Craig it received a 27% on Rotten Tomatoes so I'm going to go with a yes on that one. There's always Snatch and Layer Cake.